# Tornado blocks when I try and save to MongoDB

Tags: tornado

I was trying to make a web spider via tornado. I want to save the comments to my disk or database. What should I use to make these process quickly?

Everything seems block when I try to save file,even though I use gen.coroutine.
Data base is MongoDB

Comment: Are you using [`AsyncHTTPClient`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) to fetch the file? Are you using an async driver to connect to your database?

Comment: @xyres I did use AsyncHTTPClient but the driver pymongo seems to be a blocking driver

Comment: In that case, you may want to use [Motor](https://github.com/mongodb/motor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Tornado, if you do not want Tornado to block while you are communicating with third party services you need to use an asynchronous library. There is a list of asynchronous libraries for Tornado here:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links

For your specific need you will want to look at these libraries for Mongo:

- asyncmongo - http://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo
- Motor - http://github.com/mongodb/motor/
- PyEnty - https://github.com/leodesouza/pyenty/